# Xdebug is installed, but the IDE does not listen to it

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I am working on a project and I want to use Xdebug. So far, so good.

But I don't get that darn thing working and it is stressing me out (and also my colleagues)

I am using Laravel Homestead/Vagrant with PhpStorm as IDE. The Homestead VM is a Ubuntu VM (18.04.1 LTS)

The steps I've taken to install Xdebug.

1. I've to install xdebug on my Vagrant VM, it is also loaded when you start PHP and compiled with it.

`php --ini`

```
...
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
> /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini, <
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini,
...
```

`php -v`

```
PHP 7.2.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 08:07:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with blackfire v1.24.0~linux-x64-non_zts72, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfire
```

2. I've been to `File / Settings / Languages & Frameworks / PHP`

This is the settings of my CLI Interpreter 
[image: settings]

This is the settings of Debug
[image: debug]

And this is my config file

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

How can I solve the problem that when I try to go to my website, the debugger does not work (PhpStorm is listening to incoming connections and I am using a Firefox plugin for Xdebug)

Comment: You need to change the `xdebug.remote_host` parameter in php.ini of the remote interpreter to an address the VM can use to connect to the host machine, as `xdebug.remote_connect_back` probably detects a wrong one.

Comment: I found for my version of PHPStorm, I had to install a browser extension - after that it ran fine. See here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

Comment: I already have that extension, just a random popular one that I found in the Firefox Store @treyBake